# Почему выводит [object Object]?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вот часть кода в которой содержится функция.[image: Результат]

Comment: А что должно выводить?

Comment: Приводите, пожалуйста, код текстом. Так с ним удобнее работать.

Comment: Результат вычислений

Comment: Грубо говоря, потому что `[{}].toString()` это `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 4):

У вас проблема в коде filter. dbOperation.reduce даже не вызывается. Исправьте на

```
const resultIncome = dbOperation.filter(item => item.amount > 0).reduce((acc,item)=> acc + item.amount,0)
```

Либо сразу

```
const resultIncome = dbOperation.reduce((acc,item)=> acc + item.amount >0? item.amount:0,0)
```

Аналогичная проблема с Expences

Comment: Извините за оформление. Набираю с телефона

Answer (score 3):

Потому что во время присваивания `elem.textContent = x`, этот `x` автоматически будет превращен в строку. А когда пытаются сделать строку из объекта, вызывается его встроенный метод `.toString()`, который приводит к такому результату.

```js
console.log( {}.toString() ); // [object Object]
// Объект: Возвращает строку "[object название_конструктора]"

console.log( [1, 2, 3].toString() ) // "1,2,3"
// Массив: Превращает свои элементы в строку, расставляя между ними запятые.

// Комбо:
console.log( "" + [{}, {}, {}] ); // [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Если нужно выводить массив объектов в читаемом для пользователя виде, собирайте необходимую строку вручную:

```js
let test = [
  { item: 1, amount: 100 },
  { item: 2, amount: 200 },
  { item: 3, amount: 300 },
];

let str = test.map(obj => `> item: ${obj.item} || amount: ${obj.amount}`).join("\n");

document.getElementById("pre").textContent = str;
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Или используйте [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
let test = [
  { item: 1, amount: 100 },
  { item: 2, amount: 200 },
  { item: 3, amount: 300 },
];

function showData(data) {
  return JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
}

document.getElementById("pre").textContent = showData(test);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Два подхода можно комбинировать в разных вариациях.

Comment: Да не, ошибка в filter

Comment: @AzizUmarov И там тоже)

Comment: Если исправить код то объектов не будет

Comment: Будут только числа

Comment: @AzizUmarov, автор данногоответа объясняет, почему такое происходит в общем случае. Вы же говорите про конкретный. Так что ваши оба ответа по-своему верны :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Судя по комментариям в вопросе "Результат вычислений" я что-то так не думаю. Ответ конечно полезный тут нечего спорить

Comment: @AzizUmarov, так а как это противоречит? Человек получил массив вместо числа, верно? Верно. Вы помогли ему исправить код, а автор данного ответа объяснил, откуда такое поведение берётся. Вы дали ТС рыбу, а OptimusPrime - удочку, если позволите :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov не ну про рыбу конечно аналогия дельная, что спорить. Вот ничего не имею против ответа автора. Все верно, но не думаю что ТП имел ввиду именно вывести массив в этом ввиде. Я не утверждаю лишь догадки. Тем более вопрос оформлен "сказочно". Из цикла Пойми как хош

Comment: @AzizUmarov, не спорю) С точки зрения результата мне и самому кажется, что ваш вариант ближе к тому, чего хочет добиться автор